# is it an anti-pattern using viewmodel.myData = myData in activity or fragment

Tags: android

I'm developing android apps.
Sometimes I use the viewmodel like this

```
viewmodel.myData = myData
```

because I can't use the `setMyData(myData: MyData)` in activity or fragment

But someone told me don't use like that way.
make a new function and set that data.
So I only could make the function like this `fun setMyData2(myData: MyData)` in viewmodel.

I want to know `viewmodel.myData = myData` is an antipattern in activity or fragment

Comment: Why  you "can't use the `setData(myData: MyData)` in activity or fragment"?

Comment: my mistake, not SetData but setMyData(), bacause of kotlin reserved word.

Comment: Can you show the code that doesn't work together with the error message?

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel just like data center in your application.So it is better to call function like set** in your view model。It will make your view model has more extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).